# How to apply GeometricTransformation to ArrayPlot?

Tags: plotting, geometric-transform

In a previous version of Mathematica (maybe version 7), it was possible to use `GeometricTransformation` on an `ArrayPlot`.  That doesn't seem to work anymore.

`Rotate[ArrayPlot[img], Pi/4]` works, but I want to be able to apply a more general transformation to the image. And, also I need to be able to combine that transformed image with other things that I want to draw on the plane. Right now, `Rotate[ArrayPlot` won't combine with other things like `Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2}]` via `Show`.

What I'd like to do is to display a rasterized image (say a PNG) on a coordinate grid and to be able to apply various transformations on that image in the style of GeometricTransformation. I'm not wedded to using `ArrayPlot`--that was just what I used in my notebook from 11 years ago!

Any suggestions for accomplishing this in a more recent version of Mathematica?

Comment: Internally, `ArrayPlot[]` produces a `Raster[]` object, so you could extract that and apply your transformations to it: `With[{ras = Cases[ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {5, 5}], ColorFunction -> Hue], _Raster, Infinity]}, Graphics[{Directive[FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Thick]], Rotate[{ras, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 5}]}, Pi/3]}]]`. If this does not suit your needs, edit your question to explain why.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!  That tip that ```Raster``` was the graphics primitive that would work with ```GeometricTransformation``` was perfect.